# How to change the contrast color of ngx-monaco-diff-editor?

Tags: ngx-monaco-editor

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIlT8.png)
Hello, I hope you're doing well.
I'm trying to change the contrast color of ngx-monaco-diff-editor, but it doesn't work.
I need to change the color of left panel from pink to blue and also the color of right panel from green to yellow.
How should I do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.